# Serverless option as default value for option not working

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless, serverless-architecture

Hi I am trying to do the following with serverless:
If I am not giving an option I want it to pick another option

```
${opt:fb,${opt:environment,'dev'}}
```

However something is wrong as this error always appear as I call `sls deploy`:

```
A valid option to satisfy the declaration 'opt:fb,dev' could not be found.
```

I do not understand what's wrong as apparently it seem to pick the value correctly.
Able to help me out? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get this type of interpolation working correctly, wrap the inner variable with double quotes:

```
${opt:fb, "${opt:environment, 'dev'}"}
```

---

This pattern is especially useful for setting up `default -> envvar -> CLI option` heirarchies.

For example:

```
stage: ${opt:stage, "${env:stage, 'dev'}"}
region: ${opt:region, "${env:region, 'us-east-1'}"}
```

Stage and region each have a default, which can be overridden by an environment variable, which can in turn be overridden by a CLI argument.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply, I tried with your suggestion, here is my serverlessVars file: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Sxzn8r7dZ8/ and here my step function yml: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Mk53fwhjsc/ Every time I run `sls deploy --environment dev` the following error appears: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GBW2v3bx4K/

Comment: This may have changed since this answer, but with Serverless 2 you can have multiple fall-backs without nesting. So the stage example above becomes `stage: ${opt:stage, env:stage, 'dev'}`

Answer (score 0):

According to your expression, you are trying to do a double condition. Looks like it doesn't work.

> ${opt:fb,${opt:environment,'dev'}}

1. ${opt:environment,'dev'} - when the *opt:environment* is undefined then value is set to **'dev'** (also maybe you meant *opt:stage*)
2. the name of the variable is built: opt:fb,dev - which cannot be found.

Try to simplify and split your options:

```
custom:
    cliEnv: ${opt:environment, 'dev'}
    conditionEnv: ${opt:fb, ${self:custom.cliEnv}}
```